# rewrite url partially working on apache htaccess

Tags: apache

My htaccess executes the first block of rewrite but it ignores the second part when am trying to clean my url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^products/(\w+)/?$ products.php?icode=$1
```

Comment: why are you writing `RewriteEngine On` again ?

Comment: it doesn't make a difference even if I remove the `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: what is wrong with my code please someone tell me.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write `RewriteEngine On` again,

and you are using the name of file in url thats why its not helping you. try something like below

```
RewriteRule ^product/(\w+)/?$ products.php?icode=$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^products/(\w+)/?$ product.php?icode=$1
```

**Rename your file name or change name in your url**

Comment: have you renamed your file ??

Comment: I did that too ... didn't help :( been racking my brains since yesterday